# C++ Custom Comparison Functors

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

I am trying to pass a custom functor into std::map.

So, I declare the following functor and the class whose member is a map in a HEADER file.

```
class Comp {
        bool g;
        public:
                Comp(bool greater) : g(greater) {}
                bool operator()(float lhs, float rhs) const {
                        if (g) return lhs >= rhs;
                        return lhs < rhs;
                }
};

class OrderBook {
        u_char OrderBookType;
        std::map<float, std::vector<float*>, Comp> OrderBookData;

        public:
                OrderBook(u_char);
                float best_bid_ask(int);
};
```

And in a .cpp file, I define the constructor for OrderBook class as follows to initialize the std::map.

```
OrderBook::OrderBook(u_char bookType)  {
        OrderBookType = bookType;
        OrderBookData(Comp(bookType == 'B'));
}
```

However, when I try to compile the program, I run into a "type does not provide a call operator" error:

```
error: type 'std::map<float, std::vector<float *>, Comp>' does not provide a call operator
        OrderBookData(Comp(bookType == 'B'));
```

I am very confused as to why I am running into this error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: An unrelated problem is that your comparison when `g` (greater) is true is not a _strict weak ordering_ because it returns true when the two values are equal. You should use `return lhs > rhs;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [initializer list syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to construct the members:

```
OrderBook::OrderBook(u_char bookType) :
    OrderBookType{bookType},
    OrderBookData{Comp{bookType == 'B'}} { }
```

At the point where you are trying to construct the map, it is already default-constructed.  The syntax you're using looks like a function call, so the compiler looks for a suitable `operator()` function on the map, but doesn't find it -- hence the error.

Comment: I realised that the following definition of the constructor also works.  `OrderBook::OrderBook(u_char bookType): OrderBookType(bookType), OrderBookData(Comp(bookType == 'B'))  {}`.   I was hoping to understand better why this is different from ```OrderBook::OrderBook(u_char bookType)  { OrderBookType = bookType; OrderBookData(Comp(bookType == 'B'));  }```.

Comment: @VimellPresadYuvarajah All data members that aren't explicitly listed in the initializer list are default-constructed. So in your code, both members are default-constructed, then you assign a value to `OrderBookType`. The next line tries to invoke `operator()` on `OrderBookData` but there isn't one -- it doesn't actually attempt to invoke a constructor at all.